# Blackberry license screen agreement like Facebook

Tags: facebook, blackberry, popup, screen, licensing

I have a "basic" license agreement screen for now, a Screen with a title set and vertical field containing a textfield, separatorfield and then 2 buttons (accept or decline).

The license is pretty long, it's annoying going all the way down (except with the storm it's pretty easy) and I want a kind of popup screen showing the license and the 2 buttons at the bottom. To give you an example, the exact SAME as the Facebook or App World application's license screen agreement!

When you scroll the text, it's going a lot faster and it's visualy great.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[This should be exactly what you want.](http://dftr.ca/?p=220)

Answer (score 1):

I use a popup screen (subclassed) with a richtextfield (RTF) on it. You can size the popupscreen and change the font size of the text (ie. scrolls faster). The combination does the trick for me. The agree/disagree buttons you can then have either right at the bottom underneath the RTF.

Comment: Thank you! I have still an issue, my popupscreen has a white background. I'm already in the event dispatcher when I push this screen. I guess that's why I don't see the Downloads folder in background. Any suggestion to fix that?

Comment: are you extending MainScreen or PopupScreen? A white background sounds like MainScreen or a derived class that overrides paint or paintbackground?

public class EulaScreen extends net.rim.device.api.ui.container.PopupScreen {
..
..
}
}

Answer (score 0):

Hmmm, I realize now that I did not log in making that original answer. Oh well, Glad I could help. I'd have commented instead of answering, but I dont have rep! So, you're welcome @Dachmt. I'll be adding in a class for global encrypted application settings (Things like "license accepted") next week to deal with that //TODO in the usage.